# bash command redirection in expect script failing with permission denied (spawn ssh user@host command > outfile)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, permissions, expect

I have this `expect` script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set pass [ exec echo my_phrase | gpg --batch --quiet --yes --passphrase-fd 0 -d /root/.password-store/ssh/my_pgp_store.gpg ]
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa ssh-user@remote-host.com /some/remote/script > /home/myuser/ssh.output
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$pass\r"
interact
```

that is supposed to read a `gpg` encrypted password, and use it to call a remote script via ssh (there are many reasons why I need to do it like that). Now, my problem is that whenever I run this script, the ssh connection is correctly set up, but it fails in writing the output of the `ssh` call with the error

```
bash: /home/myuser/ssh.output: Permission denied
```

I'm running the script as root (because I have to run it as root), and I already tried to change the permissions and ownerships of all the involved files and directories.

Comment: Consider setting up public key authentication for `ssh` instead of using `expect`.

Comment: Try running `echo foo > /home/myuser/ssh.output` on the same host & session where you're running this script. Does it work or do you get an error?

Comment: For chepner, I couldn't use that solution for many reasons I don't have the time and space to explain here. For Kenster, yes, it was sorking on the same host & session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redir char `>` is not special for expect's `spawn` command. The command

```
spawn ssh user@host command > outfile
```

means the same as

```
spawn ssh user@host "command > outfile"
```

and the redir `> outfile` will be executed on the remote host.

Try like this:

```
spawn bash -c "ssh user@host command > outfile"
expect "assword:"
send -- "$pass\r"
interact
```